# Finding out actions made at a specific date or time

Tags: windows, windows-7, monitor

We have a few candidates at our workplace who we have found to be torrenting. (Using proxies I assume to download software etc).

They have however left their torrents on there which have a date and time of initiation. 
Is it possible to check other documents made or opened at that time area?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use CTRL + F and in search box type:
     date:‎11.‎07.‎2013 
for example and you will have searching by date modified for concrete date

Source : windows common knowlege :)